# SolrJ only value of enum type

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm trying to add documents to Solr using SolrJ. Here is my class with @Field annotations:

```
public class Popular {
@Field("popular_id")
private Long popularId;

@Field("type")
private Type type;

public Long getPopularId() {
    return popularId;
}

public void setPopularId(Long popularId) {
    this.popularId = popularId;
}

public Type getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(Type type) {
    this.type = type;
}

}
```

And here is my enum:

```
public enum Type {
SERVICE,
BRAND,
CITY
}
```

Here is my method that adds documents to Solr using SolrJ:

```
private void addPopularItem(SolrClient client, Long popularId, String[] wordsArray)
    throws IOException, SolrServerException {

    Popular popular = new Popular();
    popular.setPopularId(popularId);
    popular.setType(Type.valueOf(wordsArray[1]));

    client.addBean(popular);
}
```

And my document is Solr looks like that:

```
{
    "popular_id":[1],
    "**type**":["com.XXX.XXX.XXX.indexes.popular.Type:SERVICE"],
    "id":"7306406f-4b99-4cee-9c9a-0b7ee84cd5b9",
    "_version_":1584849462071656448,
    "type_str":["com.XXX.XXX.XXX.indexes.popular.Type:SERVICE"]
}
```

Is there a way to change that type field so it has only value from Type enum instead of package + class name + value?

Comment: Exaclty the same problem encountered for me...

Comment: I haven't found any solution so I chose to store just String value.

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10653 - maybe vote there?